# Github action - node.js CI npm test hanging [Angular9]

Tags: node.js, angular, continuous-integration, karma-jasmine, github-actions

new to github actions. I've got everything set up for the most part following the tutorial on ghub's documentation for setting up a nodeJs.yml in the workers dir.

Having this issue where when it gets to the run command of **npm test** it produces a log saying that it can't open the chrome browser? it tries twice and then it just hangs there. The test suite is in jasmine/karma. At current there are no unit tests apart from the auto generated ones when you create an angular component. Please see attached photos of the .yml set up and the output from the CI action.

I'd appreciate any help you can send my way, I'm new to managing github repo's and can't seem to find any solutions on my own.

If I've missed any important details let me know :)

Thanks for your time guys!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like `ng test` is not starting an headless chrome.

Try to replace the `test` script in the `packages.json` with `ng test --watch=false --browsers=ChromeHeadless` (or add a new script dedicated for the CI runs like `citest`).